# How to package node webkit app

Tags: node.js, webkit, node-webkit

I'm developing my first node webkit app. I'm confused about packing the files. Is the end product a single file that can be executed ?

```
The end result will not be a single executable, you must also include some DLLs in your zip-file.
```

These line in github made me more confused.

- How is the packaging done ?
- Do I need to include the webkit files also in the package or just the files I have created ?

Answer (score 0):

I packaged my node-webkit app successfully for various platforms by using the below gulp script. Below is the script which is self explanatory.

Reference : [https://github.com/nwjs/nwbuilder/blob/master/example/Gulpfile.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder/blob/master/example/Gulpfile.js)

```
var NwBuilder = require('nw-builder');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('nw', function () {

    var nw = new NwBuilder({
        version: '0.12.3',
        files: '../nodepoc/**',
        platforms: ['osx64','win32','win64']

    });

    // Log stuff you want
    nw.on('log', function (msg) {
        gutil.log('nw-builder', msg);
    });

    // Build returns a promise, return it so the task isn't called in parallel
    return nw.build().catch(function (err) {
        gutil.log('nw-builder', err);
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['nw']);
```

Save the file as `gulpFile.js`. In terminal , simply run gulp command in the same location as that of the gulpFile.js and it will download the necessary node-webkit distributions for the platforms and build the package for you.